# Mac SSH Connection Timeout To Other Computers

Tags: macos, ssh, timeout, rsync

When I woke up today my mac can not ssh into any computer on my home network, I receive the `ssh: connect to host IP_ADD port 22: Operation timed out`. I was just using ssh last night and did not change any configurations, all I did was use the mac to ssh into two machines and tell one tell one to rsync to another. I am running OSX 10.14.1 Mojave.

I am still able to ssh into my cloud server using my Mac:

```
ssh root@cloud_server_ip 
Last login: Sun Nov 25 07:06:13 2018 from my_ip_address
root@cloud_machine:~#
```

***So it seems to be an issue on my local network. When I log into my Linux computers, they are able to ssh into each other. The problem is related to the Mac and ssh on my local network only ***

I tried diagnosing some online help already to make sure it was looking on port 22, so I will post some outputs of those commands below. In addition, I've restarted my computer 4 times and restarted the linux machines I want to remote into.

using `ssh -v user@ip`

```
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to IP [IP] port 22.
ssh: connect to host IP port 22: Operation timed out
```

using `traceroute IP`:

```
1  dsldevice (192.168.1.254)  26.208 ms  1.868 ms  1.648 ms
2  107-213-192-1.lightspeed.tukrga.sbcglobal.net (107.213.192.1)  47.442 ms  5.552 ms  8.436 ms
3  76.239.207.154 (76.239.207.154)  3.128 ms  9.490 ms  7.191 ms
4  * * *
5  * * *
6  * * *
7  * * *
```

using `cd /etc/ssh/` then running `cat sshd_config` and recieved the following output:

```
#pass locale information
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
# no default banner path
#Banner none
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

I have no idea how to fix this or what could have happened overnight. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by copying your public ssh key into the authorized_keys files of your other computers. Your public key should be located in your .ssh folder, with a name which ends with .pub, for example id-rsa.pub.

EDIT

Since DeFr0st has a comment that led two people to the solution, I quote it here in my answer for future visitors:

> This is awkward...it turns out my power went out last night, and when
> my modem rebooted it must have turned wifi back on. I am using
> ippassthrough. Anyway long story short, my mac default connected to
> the other network when it came online. Once I realized this, it
> started working again. *sigh, thanks for your help mate.

Comment: This did not solve the issue. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @DeFr0st is there a firewall involved?

Comment: This is awkward...it turns out my power went out last night, and when my modem rebooted it must have turned wifi back on. I am using ippassthrough. Anyway long story short, my mac default connected to the other network when it came online. Once I realized this, it started working again.

*sigh, thanks for your help mate.

Comment: After fighting with my ssh setup for hours, reading @DeFr0st comment fixed my issue.  I had previously restarted my computer, and my VPN was no longer connected 

Comment: @LucasScott thanks for pointing that out. I have added the content of that comment to my answer, so if there are people having similar issues in the future, they might find the solution in an easier manner.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and fixed it.

```
nano /Users/myName/.ssh/config
```

delete:

```
Host theIP
  HostName theIP
  User myName
```

and seconds later, its ok.